# Share a boolean property between the mainviewmodel and the others viewmodels in Stylet MVVM (vb.net)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, stylet

I'm working on a wpf app using Stylet MVVM framework (VM first approach).
In MainViewModel I have a property called IsProjectLoaded, that work as a flag to known if the user has loaded it and do proper actions.
This flag should be triggered from the others VMs, one is for example OpenProjectViewModel (used to actually open the file project).
Later I'll need to share the data loaded as well
Which is the simplest way to have di "Global Flag/property" shared?

Comment: In MVVM Light you can use messaging to notify between view models, maybe this Stylet has a similar set of functionality?

Comment: If I correctly understand what it is messaging, I think Stylet have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Public Property and onpropertychange

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think so.